# PL/SQL Inserting into a table minus another table but inserting another column at the same time

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a small problem, say I have **a table with 5 columns**, I insert into that table using `MINUS` from **another table that has 4 columns**.

I am having **problem inserting a (null) or ' ' value into the 5th column** when I do that statement as it says:
`invalid number of columns selected` (table I am minusing from does not have the 5th column)

This is my code I use for the insert into statement

```
INSERT INTO my_table(SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM that_table 
MINUS SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM my_table);
```

This code works, it copies whatever I need if I don't create a 5th column, is there a way to insert into my table values from the other table alongside a 5th column in my_table?

Thank you

Comment: thank you for the proposed edit DKS :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question, you want to select all records from `that_table` and insert those into `my_table` where the first 4 columns don't exist, using `null` as the value for the 5th column?  If so, you can use `not exists`:

```
insert into my_table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
select col1, col2, col3, col4, null
from that_table tt
where not exists (
    select 1
    from my_table mt
    where tt.col1 = mt.col1 and tt.col2 = mt.col2 
      and tt.col3 = mt.col3 and tt.col4 = mt.col4
    )
```

---

You should also be able to use `Minus`, just make sure you have the same number of columns and same data types:

```
insert into my_table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
select col1, col2, col3, col4, null
from that_table
minus
select col1, col2, col3, col4, null
from my_table
```

Comment: Apologies for not making my question clearer, that_table contains data that I need to copy over to my current table, but my current table I have created an extra column. I need data to copy from that_table to my_table and insert null value in the 5th column for every record copied. 
I'll try this method to see if I can get anything.

Comment: @user3674993 -- I believe this should do just that.  You could also use `MINUS` -- just make sure both queries return the same number of columns (presumably null for the last column for both).  I just prefer this method.

Comment: ah! I tried doing similar thing except inserting NULL only in FROM my_table, solution was quite obvious!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert only the selected columns, then try this:

`insert into my_table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) select col1, col2, col3, col4, null from that_table;`

You can find more information at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: thank you for the insight mate, I will take a look at the link.